# failed to mkdir /opt/cpanel/ea-php81/root/usr/share/tests/pecl/mongodb/scripts

Tags: mongodb

I want to install MongoDB on Cpanel

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php81/root/usr/bin/pecl install mongodb
```

but get this error

[image]

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/984422) when asking a question.

Comment: I have same error